# How to set the focus on the last element in a list view in android

Tags: android, listview

I am loading elements in a ListView at runtime and asking user if he wants to load more elements on a button click.What i want to achieve is that the focus should be on the last element of the listview and not on the first element.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the function [`setSelection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29).

To go to the last element use something like this:

```
listview.setSelection(listview.getAdapter().getCount()-1);
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to use these parameters in your list view:

`Scroll lv.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);`

Set the head of the list to its bottom `lv.setStackFromBottom(true);`

You can also set these parameters in XML, eg. like this:

```
ListView
...
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
android:stackFromBottom="true" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like:

```
listView.setSelection(yourItemArray.size()-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lv.setSelection(lv.getChildCount()-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the list view from the bottom use below thing .

ListView

android:stackFromBottom="true" />

Its working for me.